# is dot.net 2.0 pre installed on XP and Vista machines after reinstall?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, .net-framework

Do XP and Vista come with the .NET Framework Version 2.0 out of the box? Or do they need a service pack installing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of the both, neither version of Windows has the .NET Framework installed. Windows Vista has the .NET Framework 3.0 available as a "Windows Feature", which will also install the .NET Framework 2.0